# How can we speed up the query*

Tags: mysql

I have written this code to query the mysql tables  customerselections, companies and companycampaigns. The tables have  indexes on necessary fields.

The query time (without caching) is around 0,30.  I think query time is high  considering concurrent connections. Is it possible to rewrite in a different way to speed up the query time?

```
SELECT  
customerselections.customer_id, 
customerselections.selectedcompany_id,
customerselections.selection_id,

companycampaigns.campaign_id,
companycampaigns.company_id,
companycampaigns.campaign_title,
companycampaigns.campaign_detail,
companycampaigns.published,

companies.company_logo,
companies.company_id,


FROM  customerselections
LEFT JOIN companies ON customerselections.selectedcompany_id=companies.company_id 
LEFT  JOIN companycampaigns ON  companycampaigns.company_id=companies.company_id AND companycampaigns.published='1'
WHERE customerselections.customer_id='$customerid'  LIMIT $offset,$limit
```

Comment: The only thing I would say is only use a `LEFT JOIN` if you need one. Do you need one?

Comment: do you have an index on join fields (like company_id) and filter fields (like customer_id) ?

Comment: @Youn Elan; yes, those fields have indexes

Comment: @Jack Pettinger : I don't know. Maybe, using subqueries woud be better. I am stucked. That is why I ask for help.

Comment: @mustafa What I mean is;  try changing the `LEFT JOIN`'s to `INNER JOIN`'s. If the results display what you want to see then stick with `INNER`'s, they will run quicker.

Comment: @Jack Pettinger: I have also tried INNER JOIN. It takes aproximately same query time.

Answer (score 0):

Select based on field like `customerselections.customer_id` is slower comparing to selecting all rows as server does not have to do any filtering. So this will give a minor boost.

```
SELECT  
customerselections.*,
companycampaigns.*,
companies.*
FROM  customerselections
LEFT JOIN companies ON customerselections.selectedcompany_id=companies.company_id 
LEFT  JOIN companycampaigns ON  companycampaigns.company_id=companies.company_id AND companycampaigns.published='1'
WHERE customerselections.customer_id='$customerid'  LIMIT $offset,$limit
```

Comment: this pruduces nearly the same query time.

Comment: @mustafa, Hence I said minor boost. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a composite index on `companycampaigns (company_id, published)` and review the `EXPLAIN` plan to see if it helps.